On a couple of binomial distributions
Consider two binomial distributions $\mathcal{B}(m;n_1,p_1)$, $\mathcal{B}(m;n_2,p_2)$ and consider a given integer $\overline{m}\leq \min\{n_1, n_2\}$. Is it possible to find a combination of $n_1 \neq n_2,p_1,p_2$ so that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}(\overline{m};n_1,p_1)=\mathcal{B}(\overline{m};n_2,p_2)\neq 0
\end{equation}
?
To be honest, I have no idea how to get a rigorous answer to this question. The only thing that comes to my mind is to set the equation
\begin{equation}
\binom{n_1}{\overline{m}} p_1^{\overline{m}}(1-p_1)^{n_1-\overline{m}}=
\binom{n_2}{\overline{m}} p_2^{\overline{m}}(1-p_2)^{n_2-\overline{m}}
\end{equation}
fix $n_1 \neq n_2,p_1$ and try to solve it with respect $p_2$.
I have a mild suspect, essentially based on nothing, that the answer is no.

Guess some easy solutions may be found when $\overline{m}=0$.
